# spring-amqp RabbitMQ dynamically change publisher-confirms

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Is there a way to change publisher-confirms per message? We have a rest layer that receives the message and publishes to RabbitMQ. Based on certain message properties, we decide whether publisher confirm is needed or not.

Is there a way to override, publisher-confirms while sending message?

Comment: How about just ignore confirms for those certain messages?

Comment: once the connection is created, the expense of confirming a message is still there, even if you ignore the confirms. As @Gary suggested, i was trying to use 2 connections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; we have to add a bunch of scaffolding to support returns. Also, channels are cached and there is no way to turn off confirms for a channel once set. We'd have to keep 2 different caches.

If you wish to use conditional confirms, you could define two connection factories (and templates), one with confirms enabled, one not, and select which template to use at runtime.

**EDIT**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So41131612Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So41131612Application.class, args);
        context.getBean("normalTemplate", RabbitTemplate.class).convertAndSend("foo", "foo");
        context.getBean("confirmingTemplate", RabbitTemplate.class).convertAndSend("", "foo", "foo",
                new CorrelationData("foo"));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        context.getBean(RabbitAdmin.class).deleteQueue("foo");
        context.close();
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue foo() {
        return new Queue("foo");
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public CachingConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory() {
        return new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
    }

    @Bean
    public CachingConnectionFactory confirmingCf() {
        CachingConnectionFactory cf = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
        cf.setPublisherConfirms(true);
        return cf;
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpTemplate normalTemplate(@Qualifier("rabbitConnectionFactory") CachingConnectionFactory normalCf) {
        return new RabbitTemplate(normalCf);
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpTemplate confirmingTemplate(@Qualifier("confirmingCf") CachingConnectionFactory confirmingCf) {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(confirmingCf);
        rabbitTemplate.setMandatory(true);
        rabbitTemplate.setConfirmCallback((cd, ack, cause) -> {
            System.out.println("Correlation:" + cd + " ack: " + ack);
        });
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Garry, Thats what I tried, before posting, but was running into issues. How do we use different set of configuration properties for each of these ConnectionFactories ? Is there a sample available. I am using Java Config

Comment: I am not sure what "issues" you had but I added an example boot app and it works ok for me.